# Laravel Implement Api-key and Bearer token

Tags: jwt, laravel-9, bearer-token, api-key

Please help, I'm trying to implement the api key and bearer token or jwt, I want to ask for advice on how to use the api key without the bearer token because if you use the bearer token you need login authentication to renew it, whereas the api key can be stored for a period of one month until it expires.

is there a best way to combine the two, api-key and jwt ?
Or do you have to use both to access data, not just the api key, so you have to log in continuously if the session has expired even though the api-key has not expired?